# OpenShift: rhc setup error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, rubygems, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I am setting up my openshift connection for the first time following [this](https://openshift.redhat.com/community/get-started#cli) guide but `rhc setup` throws the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find rhc (>= 0) amongst [ZenTest-4.8.2, actionmailer-3.2.8, actionpack-3.2.8, activemodel-3.2.8, activerecord-3.2.8, activeresource-3.2.8, activesupport-3.2.8, addressable-2.3.2, annotate-2.5.0, arel-3.0.2, autotest-4.4.6, autotest-notification-2.3.4, autotest-rails-pure-4.1.2, autotest-standalone-4.5.9, bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1, bootstrap-sass-2.0.4.0, builder-3.0.4, builder-3.0.3, builder-3.0.0, bundler-1.1.5, capybara-1.1.2, childprocess-0.3.5, coffee-rails-3.2.2, coffee-script-2.2.0, coffee-script-source-1.4.0, coffee-script-source-1.3.3, daemons-1.1.9, diff-lcs-1.1.3, erubis-2.7.0, eventmachine-0.12.10, excon-0.16.2, execjs-1.4.0, factory_girl-4.1.0, factory_girl_rails-4.1.0, ffi-1.1.5, guard-1.4.0, guard-rspec-1.2.1, guard-spork-1.2.0, heroku-2.30.5, heroku-api-0.3.4, hike-1.2.1, i18n-0.6.1, i18n-0.6.0, journey-1.0.4, jquery-rails-2.2.0, jquery-rails-2.1.3, jquery-rails-2.1.1, jquery-rails-2.0.2, json-1.7.6, json-1.7.5, launchy-2.1.2, libnotify-0.5.9, libwebsocket-0.1.5, listen-0.5.2, mail-2.4.4, mime-types-1.19, multi_json-1.5.0, multi_json-1.3.6, mysql2-0.3.11, netrc-0.7.7, nokogiri-1.5.5, polyglot-0.3.3, rack-1.4.4, rack-1.4.1, rack-cache-1.2, rack-ssl-1.3.2, rack-test-0.6.2, rack-test-0.6.1, rails-3.2.8, railties-3.2.8, rake-10.0.3, rake-0.9.2.2, rb-inotify-0.8.8, rdoc-3.12, rest-client-1.6.7, rspec-2.11.0, rspec-core-2.11.1, rspec-expectations-2.11.3, rspec-expectations-2.11.2, rspec-mocks-2.11.3, rspec-mocks-2.11.2, rspec-rails-2.11.0, rubygems-bundler-1.0.7, rubyzip-0.9.9, rvm-1.11.3.5, sass-3.2.5, sass-3.2.1, sass-rails-3.2.6, sass-rails-3.2.5, selenium-webdriver-2.25.0, spork-0.9.2, sprockets-2.1.3, sqlite3-1.3.6, sqlite3-1.3.5, sqlite3-ruby-1.3.3, sys-proctable-0.9.1-universal-linux, thor-0.17.0, thor-0.16.0, tilt-1.3.3, treetop-1.4.12, treetop-1.4.10, tzinfo-0.3.35, tzinfo-0.3.33, uglifier-1.3.0, uglifier-1.2.7, uglifier-1.2.3, webrat-0.7.3, xpath-0.1.4] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rhc:22:in `<main>'
```

Am I missing something? 
Linux mint 12

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem. Worked for me by running

```
sudo rhc setup
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you install *rhc* properly (step two of the guide you are mentioning)? Looks like it is not installed or your ruby environment is somehow setup wrong. I would assume *rhc --help* shows the same error, right? What's about *which rhc*?

Without more information about your setup it is hard to give more help. Personally I like to manage my ruby installations via [rvm](https://rvm.io/), but that is absolutely no must.